# Show simple yes/no dialog box in SharePoint webpart

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I'd like to show a confirmation dialog box after clicking a button in a SharePoint webPart. I looked into the webPart project files, but there is no HTML file where I could add a small script so that the user sees the dialog box before reposting the page. Any ideas as to how I should go forward with this?

Answer (score 0):

@Rafael you can use visual webpart.In visual webpart you can add button and javascript both.